# Change slave's IP

Tags: jenkins

Had an existing slave node that performed jobs perfectly.

Recently replaced said slave node with a new machine and different IP address.

I want to edit the IP of the old slave node to use the IP of the new slave node, but keep all the old configuration.  However, when I go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> myNode, -> configure...I don't see anywhere to edit the IP.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have installed **SSH Slaves plugin**.

1) Go to

```
Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> myNode -> configure
```

2) Check the **Launch method** option, 
Select **Launch slave agents on on Unix machines via SSH** option.

Check the **Host** option is present.You can edit your IP Address.

3) Also Click on Advanced you can get more options regarding slave node like port etc.